# How can I stop R when using a tcltk radio button?

Tags: r

I've used the code here: http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/Radiobuttons.html to ask a user question.

But R doesn't wait for the user to respond - the code continues to run, and so any subsequent code that tries to use the response is missing.

Here's my full code, I'd like testVal to be stored (it's the answer).

```
require(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
rb1 <- tkradiobutton(tt)
rb2 <- tkradiobutton(tt)
rb3 <- tkradiobutton(tt)
rb4 <- tkradiobutton(tt)
rb5 <- tkradiobutton(tt)
rbValue <- tclVar(NA)
tkconfigure(rb1,variable=rbValue,value=1)
tkconfigure(rb2,variable=rbValue,value=2)
tkconfigure(rb3,variable=rbValue,value=3)
tkconfigure(rb4,variable=rbValue,value=4)
tkconfigure(rb5,variable=rbValue,value=5)

tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="What's your answer?"))
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="1"),rb1)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="2"),rb2)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="3"),rb3)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="4"),rb4)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="5"),rb5)            


testVal <- NA 

OnOK <- function()
{
    rbVal <- tclvalue(rbValue)
    tkdestroy(tt)
    testVal <<- rbVal
    print(rbVal)
    #return(rbVal)
}
OK.but <- tkbutton(tt,text="OK",command=OnOK)
tkgrid(OK.but)
tkfocus(tt)

cat(testVal)
```

Comment: there is a simple (and dumb) solution: add `repeat if(!is.na(testVal)) break` before `cat(testVal)`...

Comment: This idea does not work, when somebody closes the tktoplevel (without any rado selection) from the cross X button, which is always by default available on title bar's right corner.   @Ferdinand.kraft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an object `done` that is a tcl variable and use the function `tkwait.variable` to tell R to wait to proceed until that variable changes values.

Then incorporate a line in your function `OnOK` that changes the value of `done`. So,

```
## New object 'done'
done <- tclVar(0)

OnOK <- function()
{
    rbVal <- tclvalue(rbValue)
    tkdestroy(tt)
    testVal <<- rbVal
  ## When OK button is pressed, value of 'done' is changed
    tclvalue(done) <- 1
    print(rbVal)
    #return(rbVal)
}
OK.but <- tkbutton(tt,text="OK",command=OnOK)
tkgrid(OK.but)
tkfocus(tt)

## Tell R to wait for change in value of 'done'
tkwait.variable(done)

cat(testVal)
```

Comment: This idea does not work, when somebody closes the tktoplevel (without any rado selection) from the cross X button, which is always by default available on title bar's right corner.